# How to compare two files' creation date?

Tags: batch-file

Using batch for XP, how can I compare the creation dates of two files with a function isMoreRecentThan(pathToFile1,pathToFile2) that returns true or false ?

The solution should run without admin rights (and in particular should NOT use wmic).

Comment: Couple of items here - are the files in the same directory, and do you want the creation date or the last-updated date?

Comment: You should provide your `date` format.

Comment: Command prompt != DOS.

Comment: @peter: 1/ no the files are not in the same directory, but I don't think this is really relevant, I have their full path, and if required, you are allowed to copy them temporarily into a temp folder to compare them. 2/ I am interested in the creationDate, but I think the last updated date should be quite similar, right? 
........................
endoro: How can I provide my date format, please ?

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/" %%T in ('forfiles /m file1 /C "cmd /c echo @fdate"') do set date1=%%V%%U%%T
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/" %%T in ('forfiles /m file2 /C "cmd /c echo @fdate"') do set date2=%%V%%U%%T
if %date2% GTR %date1% *some command here*
```

You can also use @ftime for more precise comparing.**And.**  forfiles is not native command for windows XP and 2003 and you'll have to download and install windows 2003 resource kit tools if you are not using newer OS

**EDIT(for XP and 2003):**

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=/: " %%T in ('for %%a in ^(FILE1^) do echo %%~ta') do (
 if "%%Y" EQU "PM" (
  set /a "hour=%%W+12"
 ) else (
    set hour=%%W
 )
 set time1=%%V%%U%%T!hour!%%Y
 )

 for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=/: " %%T in ('for %%a in ^(FILE2^) do echo %%~ta') do (
 if "%%Y" EQU "PM" (
  set /a "hour=%%W+12"
 ) else (
    set hour=%%W
 )
 set time2=%%V%%U%%T!hour!%%Y
 )
 if !time1! GTR !time2! *do something*

 endlocal
```

you'll need to change FILE1 and FILE2 with relevant values

**LAST EDIT**

```
@echo off


call :isOlder     "C:\test.file1" "C:\test.file2"

goto :eof

:isOlder [%1 path to first file ; %2 path to second file]
    setlocal
    call :get_file_c_time  "%~1" time1
    call :get_file_c_time  "%~2" time2
    if "%time1%" LEQ "%time2%"  ( 
      echo YES 
     ) else (
      echo NO
     )
goto :eof

:get_file_c_time [ %1 path to file; %2 variable to assign value  ]
    set file_path=%~1

    if not exist "%file_path%" echo file %1 does not exist&& exit /b 1

    if "%~2" equ "" echo need a secont parameter && exit /b 2

    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

    for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=/:.гчЈз " %%T in ('dir /tc "%file_path%"') do (
     if "%%Y" EQU "PM" (
      set /a "hour=%%W+12"
     ) else (
        set hour=%%W
     )
     set ftime=%%V%%U%%T!hour!%%X
     goto :endfor
    )
:endfor

endlocal & set "%~2=%ftime%"
goto :eof
```

now you can use the **:isOlder** subroutine

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention I am using XP, sorry. So how to download what you're talking about, and how to install it (again without admin rights). Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but `forfiles` shoes the `last-writing-date` ,  not the `creation-date`.

Comment: Would it be possible to further modify the script to make it a function isMoreRecentThan(file1,file2) that returns true if file1 is more recent than file2, and false otherwise please ?

Comment: @Endoro - may be it will be not possible without `WMIC`

Comment: you can get the `creation date` without "wmic" , but the OP **must** provide his full date and time format.

Comment: @Car981 yes it's possible...Will do it later.Have a little patience :)

Comment: You're not talking about the result I get from 'date /t', are you ? The result I get is 17/05/2013, but I would be interested in comparing more than just days. I'd like to have at least the comparison to the seconds.

Comment: This makes no sense. The operating system provides file times only for `hh:mm`, not seconds.

Comment: Well when I go into the properties of my file, I can see "created on:" and a date to the seconds. But whatever, if it is only to the minutes, it's ok too. But not days, definitely.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In the properties are seconds ... but the "dir" command on the command line displays only hours:minutes. You can try it. You should also read the man page from [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html).

Comment: Sure then I'd be just fine with minutes. The date format in dir is 17/05/2013  15:01. (two spaces). Any idea how to solve my issue then ?

Comment: Now I've added a script with a subroutine that compares creation of two files.Could test on your machine to see if there are needs of adjustments?

Comment: I have the minutes in `%%X` , but this can be fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: files to be compared
SET "filea=c:\mys\oldobj.txt"
SET "fileb=c:\mys\15850492.htm"
:: Create a tempdir
:Tloop
SET tempdir="%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST %tempdir%* GOTO tloop
MD %tempdir%

MOVE "%filea%" %tempdir%\a >nul
MOVE "%fileb%" %tempdir%\b >NUL
SET file
ECHO.
FOR /f %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d /o-d /tc %tempdir%') DO SET first=%%i
ECHO first file (create date) was %first%
FOR /f %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d /o-d /tw %tempdir%') DO SET first=%%i
ECHO first file (write date) was %first%
MOVE %tempdir%\a "%filea%" >nul
MOVE %tempdir%\b "%fileb%" >nul
RD %tempdir%

ECHO.
ECHO create times=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v
ECHO.
DIR %filea% %fileb% /od /tc
ECHO.
ECHO write times=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v
ECHO.
DIR %filea% %fileb% /od /tw
```

test result: (irrelevant lines excised)

```
filea=c:\mys\oldobj.txt
fileb=c:\mys\15850492.htm

first file (create date) was a
first file (write date) was b

create times=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v

 Directory of c:\mys

07/07/2012  21:40           788,960 oldobj.txt
07/04/2013  19:06            16,295 15850492.htm

write times=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v=v

 Directory of c:\mys

07/04/2013  19:06            16,295 15850492.htm
10/05/2013  14:04           788,960 oldobj.txt
```

So - yes, with this approach, it's very relevant whether the files are in the same directory because it relies on sorting the files by the relevant date.

And as demonstrated, the creation date and last-update date can vary wildly - it depends on what the file is used for. It's even possible to have a creation date that's later than the last-update date - in fact it's common since if a file is COPIED, the new file acquires the date that it was created, but the last-update date is just that - the date the original file was last updated.

Comment: Well, your answer proves that this approach requires the copy of both files, so it is slower than other methods that does not require that...

Comment: @Aacini - how I love theoretical balderdash. Just where is this famous "copy" to which you refer?

Comment: Ops, my mistake! There are not "copy" commands, but one `MD` command, four `MOVE` commands and one `RD` command that other methods don't have. And continuing with theoretical balderdash, this approach avoids to compare the dates of files in different drives, unless one of them be copied... ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is the last edit version in npocmaka's answer, but slightly modified. I have introduced these Car981's information into the code:

- a function isMoreRecentThan(file1,file2) that returns true if file1 is more recent than file2, and false otherwise
- The date format in dir is 17/05/2013 15:01

The isMoreRecentThan subroutine return an %ERRORLEVEL% equal 1 (true) if first file is more recent than second one and 0 in any other case, including if any file does not exist.

```
@echo off

call :isMoreRecentThan "C:\path1\file1.ext" "C:\path2\file2.ext"
if %errorlevel% equ 1 echo File1 is more recent than File2
goto :eof


:isMoreRecentThan [%1=path to first file ; %2=path to second file]
setlocal
call :get_file_c_time "%~1" time1
call :get_file_c_time "%~2" time2
set exitCode=0
if %time1% neq 0 if %time2% neq 0 if "%time1%" gtr "%time2%" set exitCode=1
exit /B %exitCode%


:get_file_c_time [ %1 path to file; %2 variable to assign value  ]
set %2=0
if not exist %1 exit /B
for /F "skip=5 tokens=1-5 delims=/: " %%a in ('dir /TC %1') do (
   set %2=%%c%%b%%a%%d%%e
   exit /B
)
```

Comment: +1, It's neater .Still I wanted to be more independent from the time settings.Probably not possible without checking the registry.