# How can I write a script that compares modified dates and see which one is newer?

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, command-line

Now I found some stuff using java and python, but I want something using CMD, since that is what we all already have with any Win PC.  I have a CSV that is created from an XLS file.  The XLS file gets updated frequently. I have been trying to write a script that runs at logon, that checks the XLS file and the CSV file, if the XLS is newer (more recently modified) it will run a libreoffice command that outputs it as a ";" delimited CSV.  What I was doing was

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1" %%A IN ('DIR /o:-d "\\path" ^| FIND "Part of filename"') DO SET "Chk1=%%A"
```

This gives me, as an example Chk1=1/3/2015.  IF Chk2=1/2/2015 and I do

```
IF "%Chk1%" GTR "%Chk2%" ECHO Hi
```

I get a Hi.  Issue is that New years came around, and if Chk2=12/30/2014, the same code above gives me no "Hi". I'm assuming it is ignoring the year outright and is just looking a the month and day only. The other issue this gives me is that since it is looking at the date out off 365, if I run the script within the same date, it will not see the changes. The reason being that "1/3/2015 10:24" is seen as greater than "1/3/2015 10:23" but less than "12/30/2014 06:14".

I know I can do it in powershell and other platforms too, but like I said before I don't mind installing Python, have it actually, on my pc or enabling running PS scripts on mine, but I'd like to leave others untouched, but with the ability to still do this. CMD is something everyone has and no security changes need to be made to run a batch script.

Comment: Is this comparing the dates based on the bare strings? You may need to extract M, D and Y and compare them one by one.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670666/compare-2-dates-in-a-batch-file might help you

Comment: Are both of the files in the same directory? Do you know their names?

Comment: The files are in different directories and have have different names/extensions.  Essentially the original file that gets routinely updated is name.xls and the I use a script to convert that to a ";" delimited name.csv file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set "source=c:\somewhere\file.xls"
set "target=c:\targets\file.csv"

xcopy /l /d /y "%source%" "%target%" | findstr /b /c:"1 " >nul && (
    echo "%target%" needs to be updated
)
```

This uses `xcopy` to get only the list (`/l`) of files that will be copied (without really copy them), trying to copy the source file over the target but only when the target file needs to be updated (`/d`). If the output includes at the start of the line the text `1 file` (or similar, sorry, my windows copy is in spanish) then the source file is newer than the target.

Comment: That's a great idea. This is guaranteed to work across network shares too.

Comment: Wow...I never thought of using xcopy for this.  I never really used xcopy because I've never needed the extra switches. That said, I assume something similar should be able to get done using robocopy? I know xcopy has been deprecated, so I'd like to os-proof the script.

Comment: While I will be employing xcopy, I've looked into robocopy and it has most of the same switches, minus that I do not know how to copy and rename the file using robocopy.  Robocopy allows you to set the source and destination folders, then the file that you want to copy from one to the other, but says nothing about renaming. This is an issue in that name.xls does not exist in the destination folder. Using robocopy for copying, not to check mod dates, I could just copy it and then rename it separately, but for my intent proves useless. Anybody know how to rename with robocopy?

Comment: @user3377627,*1)* while the vista `xcopy` command included the deprecation message, it is [still included](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx) in newer os versions and the message was deleted. *2)* No, robocopy does not include the option to rename the target file.

Answer (score 2):

Nearly the same solution like MC ND showed, but you don't need a pipe nor findstr.

I used this method for a small build system, as it's sometimes necessary to compare the seconds too, when you rebuild after a few seconds.

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims= " %%A in (`XCOPY /y /L /D "%~1" "%~2"`) DO (
    set "isNewer=%%A"
)
echo %isNewer%
```

Answer (score 1):

Save this as .bat:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:-d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\*jsc.exe"') do (
   set "jsc=%%v"
)


if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
   "%jsc%" /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0" 
)

%~n0.exe %*

endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%

*/

import  System;
import System.IO;

var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
var file1=arguments[1];
var file2=arguments[2];

//print(file1+"#"+file2);

var fileCreatedDate1 = File.GetCreationTime(file1);
var fileCreatedDate2 = File.GetCreationTime(file2);
var comp=fileCreatedDate1.CompareTo(fileCreatedDate2);
if (comp==0){
    print(file1+" - "+file2+":same age");
}else if (comp>0){
    print(file1+" newer than "+file2);
} else {
    print(file1+" older than "+file2);
}
Environment.Exit(fileCreatedDate1.CompareTo(fileCreatedDate2));
```

it takes two arguments - the two files and prints the result.It's also set to errorlevel using the reult of [compared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x79949f0(v=vs.110).aspx) dates.You can modify the output or change the compared dates to LastAccessed or LastModified (now uses the creation time).Does not validate the existance of the files.

It uses jscript.net , but I suppose you have instelled .NET.This way provides a good ratio of robustness and complexity of the code.
Here's a way in pure [batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16613129/388389) , but it depeneds on time settings.Also WSH (jscript/vbscript) can be used , but will require additional work to parse times as [DateCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8xh895w(v=vs.84).aspx) property does not return Date object but string.

Another approach is to use WMI queries through WMIC or WSH but this is tooooo slow.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with .net. I looked at the link you provided, but it does almost the same thing my previous script did, but also included the same mistake.  If I have two files, one modified 1/1/2015 and the other modified 12/31/2014, and I use a for /f command with the forfiles command to set the 2015 one into variable A and the 2014 into variable B to run: IF %A% GTR %B% Echo success, it fails, because it still counts 12/31/2014 as being GTR than 1/1/2014. I'm assuming CMD sees the value of the 2014 date as 365 and the value of the 2015 one as 1.

Comment: I think it boils down to there not being a newer than operator, just a GTR and LSS operator, so CMD reads the date as number that it can successfully use in a comparison.  Thanks for the help though, I was unaware of forfiles and I'd already thought of ways I can alter some pre-existing scripts using that instead of a bunch of IFs and FORs.